# Python subprocess: interacting with a shell script

Tags: python, shell, io, subprocess, interactive-shell

I have a shell script which asks the user for too many questions.

I want to answer every question that ends with `:` with a <kbd>enter</kbd>, and every question that ends with a `?` with `y`<kbd>enter</kbd>.

e.g.,

```
Enter your name:
enter

Enter your email:
enter

...

Are you sure these details are correct?
yenter
```

I have started the subprocess with:

```python
subprocess.Popen(shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdin=sp.PIPE)
```

How do I poll over the script's output, waiting for the question to appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this (I have not tested it):

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('yourprogram')
while True:
  found = child.expect ([r':$', r'\?$', pexpect.EOF])
  if found == 0:
    child.send('\n')
  elif found == 1:
    child.send('y\n')
  else:  # EOF
     return
```

Comment: +1 for pexpect which I didn't know. It seems like a very useful approach - I will try to make it work.

Comment: `pexpect.run('yourprogram', events={r':$': '\n', r'\?$': 'y\n'})`