# Interactive shell program wrapper in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell

I'm trying to run a shell program through python. I need to run a command, then while it's still running and waiting for input to continue, I need to take the output received by the program, and process that data as a string. Then I need to parse some data into that program, and simulate an enter pressing. 
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) will work for this, but to read and then write and then read again you can't use [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (because this will cause the process to end).

Instead, you'll need to work with the process's output pipe (`process.stdout` below).  This is tricky to get right, because reading on the process's `stdout` is [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770371/1062499), so you sort of need to know when to stop trying to read (or know how much output the process is going to produce).

In this example, the subprocess is a shell script that writes a line of output, and then echoes whatever you give it until it reads EOF.

```
import subprocess

COMMAND_LINE = 'echo "Hello World!" ; cat'

process = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND_LINE, shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

s = process.stdout.readline().strip()
print(s)
s2 = process.communicate(s)[0]
print(s2)
```

Gives:

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

For more complicated cases, you might think about looking at something like [pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9555538/1062499).

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) to run your shell application and use `communicate` to interact with it.

Comment: Don't forget to use universal_newlines=True if you want the output as a string (the default is False, which leads subprocess to return byte).